# Android Studio JDK 7 error. Missing styles error

Tags: java, android, sdk, java-7

I am new to android development and just downloaded Android studio and the JDK 7 and SDK. I opened my first project and was given the Error:compileSdkVersion android-21 requires compiling with JDK 7. I have already installed the JDK. I was also given Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout? Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references. Does anyone know a fix to these errors? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may check your JDK location form

`File` -- `Project Structure` -- `JDK location`

Then change JDK location to

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/YOUR_JAVA_VERSION/Contents/Home
```

To find the default JDK location, run the java_home script

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```